# (Question on best practice) Why is "using System.Text" there by default?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class, namespaces

Every time I creat a class, I see `using System.Text` that is added (amongst other `using`) by default. Every time I remove it after a while because it is unused according to ReSharper.

Am I missing a best practice? Do you use that namespace often? In which situation?

There has to be a reason why this namespace is referenced by default.

Thanks!

Comment: StringBuilder is the big banana.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **System.Text** namespace contains classes, abstract base classes and helper classes.
Say for example if you wanted to take advantage of the **StringBuilder, Decoder, Encoder, etc...**.

The classes above, plays a significant role in most cases in .net. But it is not necessary for it to be there in your code. It only applies as to when you needed it. The important thing is to know when you will need the namespace.

It is added in visual studio by default for the convenience of the developers. Same with the
**System.Linq** namespace, not all of the time you will be using it but for your convenience it is already added assuming that you would be using it and that would be up to you to remove it which is by case to case  basis.

Sometimes it would be a lot easier to delete it if it is not needed than to figure out the namespace and type when you need it :)

[More info regarding System.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**If it's not being used, it shouldn't be in the code.** If Visual Studio adds them by default, chalk that up to Microsoft just trying to make things easy for a developer, as it thinks those are very common namespaces, but depending on what you are doing they likely aren't needed in many classes, just as you experience.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like it you can always create your own item templates. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should add `using` only for those namespaces that you really reference in the code.
This way the source file will not have a huge 'using header' and fewer namespace conflicts.

As you are using Resharper it is very easy to follow this rule.

Comment: hi just asking becaouse i wonder. How can we have namespace conflicts? Don't we have namespaces to avoid comflicts?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using it, don't include the namespace. It is just automatically included because it is one of the more commonly used namespaces. I generally use it if I want to use regular expressions or string manipulation methods. But if you remove it and there are no compiler errors, *it is safe to leave it out*.